# Service that Read file from folder and send email

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have the requirements to build a service that will

Read a notification from a text file in a folder (key)

Look up in a cross reference table which phone is assigned to the key read

Send an email or text msg to the phone the phone assigned

I have don C# .net applications but not really familiar with Services.
Can someone help with would be the logic and the best way of implementing this?

Comment: Recommend adding "C#" tag and removing "asp.net" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a Windows Service to achieve this task and to read the folder you could use the FileSystemWatcher and it's event's, email sending is lot easier then this two. :)

[Simple Windows Service Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx)

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

[SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

[Email Sending using Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: You are welcome, i wrote something like that before i hope the links will help you too. :)